# Is it possible to wrap an existing function with another function using the same name in fish?

Tags: fish

I'd like to create a cd function which expands on the current cd function which (on my machine) lives at `/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.6.0/share/fish/functions/cd.fish`. Is this possible?

So something like this:

```
function cd
    if i_can_handle_it
        do_my_thing_with $argv
    else
        call /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.6.0/share/fish/functions/cd.fish $argv
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two functions with the same name. You can have a builtin, function, and external command with the same name. The standard solution to this problem is to first rename the function you want to wrap: `functions -c cd cd2`. Then define your `cd` function that calls `cd2`. Note that this works regardless of whether `cd` has already been run and thus defined because changing the name first causes it to be autoloaded.

Comment: Hmm. That's disappointing. There should be a way to chain them.